# How to show an android app which uses webview is up to date

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to develop an offline android app using simple html, css and javascript. I use website2apk software to convert the local html files to a standalone apk file.

My app contains a tariff of some random products. What i need is to notify (in-app notification) my app user if there is any update to the app.

For example, when user get connected to internet the app should automatically check for updates and if there is any update available, a warning should appear on top of the home page which says "New Update Available" which will be linked to mysite.com/newversion.apk .

Can someone suggest me what to do for this?. I can only depend Webview and pure javascript, which means no jquery.

I'm sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this feels like you are asking for someone to design and build an entire solution for you. If you post code examples of what you have tried then it will make it easier for people to fix your mistakes

Answer (score 0):

The site which hosts your apk should have an api so you can check from your app if there is any newer version available.

Comment: What do you mean by Api? The site i hosts my apk file is my own website.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to add a file (for example a json file) which contains the actual version of your app. Then you can make a web request in your app to get the file data.

Example:
get 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/appversion.json'